# Determine if legacy VTK file is valid using Python

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I need to read a legacy VTK file with Python.  I want to use the vtk module.  I've been mostly successful, but I need to be able to detect if the VTK file is valid or not before continuing and I cannot find a type-bound procedure or attribute that will do this.  Here's a minimal example of the VTK file.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Scalar Data
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS      12 double
 -6.35000002E-03  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
 -6.35000002E-03  6.35000002E-03  0.00000000E+00
  0.00000000E+00  6.35000002E-03  0.00000000E+00
 -6.35000002E-03  0.00000000E+00  3.86600012E-02
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  3.86600012E-02
 -6.35000002E-03  6.35000002E-03  3.86600012E-02
  0.00000000E+00  6.35000002E-03  3.86600012E-02
 -6.35000002E-03  0.00000000E+00  3.86600012E-02
  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00  3.86600012E-02
 -6.35000002E-03  6.35000002E-03  3.86600012E-02
 -6.35000002E-03  6.35000002E-03  3.86600012E-02
CELLS         2        18
         8         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
         8         8         9        10        11        12        13        14        15
CELL_TYPES       2
11
11
CELL_DATA       2
SCALARS testdata float
LOOKUP_TABLE default
  1.0000E+00
```

The error in this file is that there is only 1 cell data given when the header indicates there should be two.  Here's my python file to read this data.

```
import vtk 
from vtk.util import numpy_support as VN

f1=vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
f1.SetFileName('test.vtk')
f1.ReadAllScalarsOn()
f1.Update()
arr=VN.vtk_to_numpy(f1.GetOutput().GetCellData().GetArray('testdata'))
print arr
```

And here's the output:

```
Generic Warning: In /home/vagrant/pisi/tmp/VTK-6.3.0-3/work/VTK-6.3.0/IO/Legacy/vtkDataReader.cxx, line 1379
Error reading ascii data. Possible mismatch of datasize with declaration.
```

[  1.00000000e+00   7.84727140e-44]

So you see it is detecting the inconsistency, but it doesn't crash the code.  Instead, my numpy array gets a bogus value in the array. Is there a way to get a read error back from vtk so I can handle it?  Or is there some procedure that will parse the VTK file and tell me if it's valid before reading it?

Comment: Just to update anyone interested in this, I ended up writing my own Python function that reads a VTK file and checks that the number of defined cells matches the number of cells present.  It returns true if everything checks out and false otherwise.  Not the best coding practice if a method does exist in the VTK module, but I couldn't figure it out and needed a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IsFileValid` or `IsFileUnstructuredGrid` method of the data reader class.

Comment: Yes, I tried these originally, but they appear to have no effect.  If I add 'print f1.IsFileValid('testdata')' it returns 0 whether the test.vtk file is correct or wrong.  Likewise, calling f1.IsFileUnstructuredGrid() returns 1 regardless of the vtk file being correct or wrong.

Comment: Why are you checking file test.vtk with `IsFileValid('testdata')`? You should be checking `IsFileValid('test.vtk')`. Also, how do you determine that the vtk file is correct or not?